# Having trouble debugging goose up/down command

Tags: postgresql, go, goose

Following project 3 tutorial at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=un6ZyFkqFKo (around 7:20:00). He suggests using goose to do database migration.

File 001_users.sql:

```
-- +goose Up
CREATE TABLE users (
    id UUID PRIMARY KEY,
    created_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    updated_at TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
    name TEXT NOT NULL
);

-- + goose Down
DROP TABLE users;
```

Ran from command line:

```
goose postgres postgres://<user>:<password>@localhost:5432/rssagg up  
2024/02/19 15:59:37 OK   001_users.sql (5.95ms)
2024/02/19 15:59:37 goose: successfully migrated database to version: 1
```

Check in postgres SQL for the rssagg tables, no users table is created. (even after refresh)

Not sure where to troubleshoot, since I can't seem to find documents to talk about how to troubleshoot goose.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try to add the argument `-v` to enable the verbose mode, perhaps get more information.

Comment: Ugh - that extra space in the comment line for -- + goose Down was the culprit. I somehow missed that. It would be nice if there was some sort of error emitted when goose doesn't have a well formed file.